# Recursive Function to find Max value between 2 integers

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm trying to create a recursive function that finds the maximum number in an array between a low and a high integers.

I have tried this function that helps find the maximum element in array recursively. I'm just having trouble on how to add to the function that takes in a low and a high integers to find the max between those 2.

```
int findMaxRec(int A[], int n) 
{ 
    // if n = 0 means whole array has been traversed 
    if (n == 1) 
        return A[0]; 
    return max(A[n-1], findMaxRec(A, n-1)); 
}
```

the goal is to have a function that looks something like this:

```
int findMaxBetwen(int A[], int low, int high){
      //Here is where I need help integrating if lets say the array is A[] = 5,6,7,8
      // Call findMaxBetwen(A[], 5, 8) and the output gives 7 because that is the max between the 3 
      //integers.
}
```

Comment: what is the problem? I dont know how to answer this without spoiling all the fun for you

Comment: hint: in your current function, what does it cause to stop at the first element? what does it cause to start with the last element? Identify those two and replace it with starting at `high` and stopping at `low`

Comment: I'm still a bit confused as of now in my driver code n is represented as the sizeof(A)/ sizeof(A[0]) this gives the size of the length of the array. So should I just replace the n part of my current code with the low and the high??

Comment: what driver code? Should you? I dont know, because I dont know the code. What happens when you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**update:** C++17 now defines a function [std::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) that can return the size of an array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int findMaxRec(const int[] A, const int &n)
{
  if (n <= 0) throw "error: array is empty...";
  if (n == 1) return A[0];
  return std::max(A[n - 1], findMaxRec(A, (n - 1)));
}

int findMaxRec(const int[] A)
{
  return findMaxRec(A, std::size(A));
}

const int& findMaxRec(const int &i)
{
  return i;
}
```

If you dont have C++17, would you consider using a list?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

int findMaxRec(const std::list<int> &L)
{
  if (L.size() == 0) throw "error: list is empty...";
  return (*std::max_element(L.begin(), L.end()));
}
```

`findMaxBetwen` can be implemented as a function template:

```
template<typename T> int findMaxBetwen(const T &data, int low, int high)
{
  int i = findMaxRec(data);
  if (i <= low) return low;
  if (i >= high) return high;
  return i;
}

//....

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  std::list<int> a = {5, 6, 7, 8, 10};
  cout << findMaxBetween(a, 5, 8) << '\n'; // output is 8

  int b[5] = {5, 6, 7, 8, 10};
  cout << findMaxBetween(b, 5, 8) << '\n'; // output is 8

  int c = 7;
  cout << findMaxBetween(c, 5, 8) << '\n'; // output is 7
}
```

Learn more about function templates at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template)